# gunicorn and flask-jwt-extended not getting current user

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, flask-jwt-extended

I've been building an app that uses flask, `flask_jwt_extended` and the decorator `@jwt_required` around protected functions that need an access token to access. From these endpoints, I can use `flask_jwt_extended`'s `get_current_user` function to fetch the currrent user.

This has been working fine while in development, but now I'm planning to serve a production application using `gunicorn`. However, when I run the `gunicorn` server, it seems like the `get_current_user` function is always returning none. For example, the following code works with `python3 -m flask run`, but not with `gunicorn run:app -b localhost:5000`. What could be the problem here?

```
@jwt_required
def get_user_by_id(user_id: str) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    # returns user when using flask run, but not with gunicorn
    curr_user = get_current_user()
```

Answer (score 1):

## Class-worker

- Do you use multiple workers and `sync` class ?
  Maybe try to look at [gunicorn worker-class](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#worker-class)

> If you try to use the sync worker type and set the threads setting to more than 1, the gthread worker type will be used instead.

- In your python configuration file or you can change worker-class directly in the command line.

> worker_class = 'gthread'

## Check your JWT_SECRET_KEY

- `JWT_SECRET_KEY` need to have the same value all over each workers